# Why is there only two packets in a TLS handshake?

Tags: tls, client, handshake

I captured my network traffic to a web server and the SSL Handshake consists only of two packets.
Why does that happen and why aren't there all the other packets?

Comment: probably is the session ID functionality, check the session id of the client hello in order to verify if you have a value, also if you upload the pcap file will help us

Answer (score 2):

You're probably seeing session resumption.  If the Client Hello and Server Hello packets both have the same `Session ID` value, then the handshake is shortened as the Client and Server 'recognize' each other.

To quote [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246):

> The client sends a ClientHello using the Session ID of the session to
> be resumed.  The server then checks its session cache for a match. If
> a match is found, and the server is willing to re-establish the
> connection under the specified session state, it will send a
> ServerHello with the same Session ID value.  At this point, both
> client and server MUST send ChangeCipherSpec messages and proceed
> directly to Finished messages.

Comment: For TLS 1.2 and below; in 1.3 (since 2018) this field is 'legacy' and always contains a dummy value whether or not resumption (and a correspondingly short handshake) is used. And in 1.2 and below, clienthello can contain no session-id but a previously issued and still valid ticket, which server accepts, per rfc4507/rfc5077.